# Choose object and then another object related to this

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

It's quite hard for me to explain what i need with words so I here is some code:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    firmware_version = models.ForeignKey(FirmwareVersion)
    devices_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

class Firmware(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    circuit_model = models.ForeignKey(Versiiplates)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

class FirmwareVersion(models.Model):
    firmware = models.ForeignKey(Firmware)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="firmware/")
    upload_date = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today())
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=2500, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.firmware.__unicode__(), self.version)
```

Is there any way to choose in admin change-form for Configuration the Firmware first and then any FirmwareVersion related to it?

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple to implement this behavior with [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). In my case Configuration class should look like this:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    firmware = models.ForeignKey(Firmware, related_name="firmware")
    firmware_version = ChainedForeignKey(FirmwareVersion, chained_field="firmware", chained_model_field="firmware", show_all="False", auto_choose=True)
    devices_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```